# Questions about MBR/GRUB

Tags: grub2, 16.04, uninstall

I have a simple question. Where is MBR (GRUB) located, it's inside a partition? And does it get removed when you format & delete the partitions of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5):

This question isn't quite as simple as you may think.

First off, MBR and GRUB aren't the same thing. [MBR](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/Master-Boot-Record-MBR) is:

> the information in the first sector of any hard disk or diskette that identifies how and where an operating system is located so that it can be boot (loaded) into the computer's main storage or random access memory. The Master Boot Record is also sometimes called the "partition sector" or the "master partition table" because it includes a table that locates each partition that the hard disk has been formatted into. In addition to this table, the MBR also includes a program that reads the boot sector record of the partition containing the operating system to be booted into RAM. In turn, that record contains a program that loads the rest of the operating system into RAM.

[GRUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB), however, is:

> a boot loader package from the GNU Project. GRUB is the reference implementation of the Free Software Foundation's Multiboot Specification, which provides a user the choice to boot one of multiple operating systems installed on a computer or select a specific kernel configuration available on a particular operating system's partitions.

A shorter version: MBR is the info on a hard drive that tells the BIOS of the computer what to boot. GRUB is a bootloader, which scans for installed operating systems and presents them in a list to choose among. (Not the best summary, but it should do for now)

---

> Where is MBR (GRUB) located, it's inside a partition?

Well, it depends. You see, there are actually at least two different ways a hard drive might be set up:

- MBR

  This was explained above, so I think I can leave it at that.
- GPT

  This is a newer standard than MBR, although it essentially does the same thing. GPT has more features and is generally more useful than MBR. However, for normal purposes, the two aren't vastly different.

(For a more in-depth explanation of the differences: http://www.howtogeek.com/193669/whats-the-difference-between-gpt-and-mbr-when-partitioning-a-drive/)

There is one difference that is very important to your question, though, and that is (U)EFI. Hard drives using GPT are compatible with EFI. MBR is not, at least not normally.

UEFI presents itself in the form of a small FAT32 partition at the very beginning of the hard drive. Inside this, operating systems that support GPT/EFI place their boot files. If the system the hard drive is on is compatible with EFI, it will first look into that EFI partition and find a boot file to load an OS. There's some sort of priority system that decides what file to boot from if there are multiple options, but I don't really know how that works.

MBR does not make use of this EFI partition. Instead, OS boot files are stored in their respective partitions, and the MBR tells the BIOS what to look for. In the case of GRUB, the normal MBR code gets replaced by the stage 1 portion of GRUB. This then passes off to the stage 1.5 part, which then passes off to stage 2. Stage 2 is the only part of the process on the partition.

This configuration is very different on Windows, but we're not here to talk about Windows.

So, finally, the answer. With both MBR and GPT, deleting just the Ubuntu partition is a bad idea. In both cases, important configurations for GRUB are stored in the respective OS partitions, while most (MBR) or all (GPT) of the actual bootloader is at the very beginning of the hard drive.

Deleting the Ubuntu partition won't delete GRUB, and will instead cause `grub rescue` to come up instead. This is why there are so many questions about removing Ubuntu and keeping Windows or removing Ubuntu and installing Windows: GRUB doesn't like to let go of the drive.

---

This leads me to the second part of your question:

> And does it get removed when you format & delete the partitions of Ubuntu?

Through the power of editing and lack of memory, I seem to have answered this above.

---

You seem to have a bit of a misunderstanding about what MBR is and what GRUB is. Hopefully, I've fixed that and answered your question as well.

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer. It clarified a lot for me. The reason I asked is because I want to leave my old HDD in a clean state (ie. remove Ubuntu and all MBR/partition table related info). How do I achieve that, considering that it's a MBR scheme? Just formatting and deleting the partitions will get rid of everything (system and partition table)?

Comment: @victorbrt Just deleting all partitions will remove boot stuff. As for wiping the partition table itself, I'm not sure. You'd have to look that up.

Comment: On MBR-partitioned drive with Grub installed in MBR Grub will not be deleted when you delete Ubuntu-partition, you only delete the configuration-files which reside in most cases in the Ubuntu-partition.

Comment: @mook765, from what I read, just going to diskpark in Windows and selecting my disk, I could do a clean" command (http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/52129-disk-clean-clean-all-diskpart-command.html) and then the MBR will be overwritten. This theoretically would remove all previous info of grub/mbr, right? My plan is just restore the MBR to "default" on this HDD because I plan to buy another SSD to leave Windows in one and Ubuntu in another, and the HDD just for general storage.

Comment: @victorbrt if you're reusing the drive yourself, there's no reason to do such an extensive wipe. Erasing the existing partitions and creating a new one should be enough.

Comment: The clean command will overwrite any hidden sector information on MBR disks so any boot-loader will be erased, but this is more than deleting a partition. If you just delete a partition this hidden information is not overwritten, only the partition-table-entry would change,thats all...

Comment: @mook765 (on your first comment) Wikipedia says that the MBR contains code to pass the boot process of to a second stage loader, which is what GRUB is. That tells me that GRUB is not in the MBR.

Comment: @ZachareeGrub is in the magic area between MBR and first partition. Grub is not in the Ubuntu-partition, so why should it be erased when you delete the partition which just points to grub. Grub is still there after deleting the Ubuntu-partition and will drop to rescue-mode because the configuration-files are deleted. You can try. It is similar to UEFI, In UEFI Grub is installed on ESP, In legacy Grub is installed in the magic space between MBR and first partition. In both cases Grub itself is not in the partition you delete. But in both cases you delete the configuration-files for Grub...

Comment: @mook765 can I have a source for this? I'm not doubting you, but I want to learn about it and edit my answer accordingly, since I was under the impression that MBR systems just had bootloaders in corresponding partitions.

Comment: @Zacharee If you install Grub to a partition it will not work unless you chainload to the boot-loader in  MBR. I will try to find some sources for you, it will take a moment...

Comment: @Zacharee [Here](http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/GRUB.htm) some deeper  info, and [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/142912/where-is-the-boot-loader-installed) something fro AskUbuntu. You will surely agree that in normal cases Grub will be installed in the MBR as first stage boot-loader.

Comment: @mook765 oh I see. The MBR is effectively replaced by GRUB's stage1 portion, which then loads GRUB from a partition. Is that correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46205/discussion-between-mook765-and-zacharee1).

Comment: @mook765 I've revised my answer.

Comment: @mook765, so, doing the "clean" command indeed removes GRUB and restores MBR from my HDD to it's original state?

Comment: @victor `clean` removes any and all partition or volume formatting from the disk. On  `MBR`-disks, only the MBR partitioning information and hidden sector information are overwritten. On GUID partition table (GPT) disks, the GPT partitioning information, including the Protective MBR, is overwritten; there is no hidden sector information. `clean all` specifies that each and every sector on the disk is zeroed, which completely deletes all data contained on the disk.Grub in MBR seems not to be overwritten. A part off Grub in Sectors2-62 are overwritten. You need `fixmbr` too...

Comment: @mook765, that's a lot of technical rich info, thank you very much. I know that I'm just going overkill, but I really wants to clean this HD for just general storage later. Doing the clean command itself doesn't restore MBR then? clean with fixmbr would do? To be clear, I just want a easy way in Windows to completely restore my HDD to it's original state, with it's default MBR for Windows.

Comment: @victorbrt If you want to use the drive as date-storage only you don't need to do anything. The MBR holds a bootloader and the partition-table. If no operating-system is installed on the drive the boot-loader in the MBR has no meaning anyway.  Using `fixmbr would reinstall Windows-bootloader on the MBR of the drive where Windows is installed, so don't bother...

Answer (score 4):

> Where is MBR (GRUB) located, it's inside a partition?

No, it's not located inside a partition. MBR (Master Boot Record) is the first sector of a *disk*, so it is 512 bytes on a 512 bytes-sectored disk.

Just to note, the first sector of a partition is actually called *Partition Boot Record* or *Volume Boot Record*.

> does it get removed when you format & delete the partitions of Ubuntu?

No, MBR is not removed when you delete partitions as it is located outside the partition range, the partition table would be updated accordingly though in such operation(s).

Comment: Partition-table will be updated accordingly when you delete a partition, so the partition-table is not going to be obsolete...

Comment: @mook765 Edited.

Answer (score 1):

With my understanding of MBR & Grub this is sort of a multipart answer. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

The MBR itself exists in 512 bytes of the 1st sector (Sector 0) of a hard drive, outside a partition space. The MBR is loaded with the boot.img file, and the boot.img file's only function is to load core.img.

The core.img exists in the next 32k of disk space (between sector's 1-63).  This also exists outside a partitioned area.  The core.img is made up of the diskboot.img (depending on the boot method), kernel.img, and the video & file system modules required to display messages & mount the /boot partition.  The core.img mounts the /boot partition & read's the grub.cfg & starts the GRUB menu system.

So with my understanding you wouldn't delete Grub itself by removing the /boot partition but the *.cfg file core.img use's to start it.