# Ubuntu's GRUB bootloader not getting detected after drive change

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, boot-time

I had HDD where I had Ubuntu 18.04 installed and I installed Ubuntu 19.10 on M2 ssd. everything was working perfectly. I planned to replace HDD with another m.2 SSD. I did. after that when i booted my laptop it can't boot GRUB bootloader. so my guess is that, GRUB was installed in that HDD Which i replaced. so what is the solution? should i replace old hdd and do something to install grub in my m.2 ssd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the HDD with the original GRUB bootloader.

Once it boots again, [find its location](https://askubuntu.com/a/957516/197910), typically in the ESP if your PC uses UEFI; if not, typically it is in the MBR.

To confirm, open a terminal and run `sudo lsblk /dev/sda` and repeat for every other drive device on the system. The partition with  **/boot** or **/boot/efi**  is where the bootloader is now.

Now, run `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` where **sdX** is the SSD you want to have GRUB live on. Some SSDs aren't named with the **sd** convention; that's why we check first, as [some have names starting with](https://superuser.com/questions/1449499/why-does-linux-list-nvme-drives-as-dev-nvme0-instead-of-dev-sda) **nvm**  .   For more detail, see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/grub-install.8.html

Comment: and is it normal that GRUB bootloader loads default OS (which is selected by default after 5 seconds) faster and other OS (which we have to manually select) slower?

Comment: a) That's the subject for a different question, unless the non-default OS does not load at all or takes more than double the time required by the default. b) I looked in https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html , https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html , https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2 , and searched here, and found no mention of slower booting _all other things being equal_. .